# Second navbar goes under the first navbar on top

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, position

Hi I am using twitter bootstrap, and I am having two nav bar but the second navbar is hidden underneath of the first one

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top"> 
 <a class="brand" href="../"></a>
 <div class="navbar">
              <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                  <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
```

and the second nav menu is

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="#home" data-toggle="tab">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#profile" data-toggle="tab">Profile</a></li>
      <li><a href="#messages" data-toggle="tab">Messages</a></li>
      <li><a href="#settings" data-toggle="tab">Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
```

here is the whole code http://jsfiddle.net/YZJ5M/

You wont be able to see my second nav as it is underneath of the first nav and I want the second nav bar to be just below it. Thank you

Comment: remove margin-left on this class .thumbnails    -------------  demo http://jsfiddle.net/YZJ5M/1/

Comment: @RohitAzad I just did that but it doesnt help me , this is what my second nav bar looks like which is under the other navigation http://jsfiddle.net/YZJ5M/2/ now and you wont see it

Comment: you want this http://jsfiddle.net/YZJ5M/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply take off the `position: fixed` rule for `navbar-fixed-bottom` and `navbar-fixed-top`. Or if you would not like to change it, add `margin-top: 43px` rule to your `tabbable` class.

Comment: do you know how I can make the css bootstrap as small as possible, there are many extra things in it that I dont use

Comment: Simply delete the rules you don't use :)